# Приложение падает на вызове DeviceIoControl

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Необходимо получить смещение разделов жёсткого диска. Я делаю это следующим образом:

```
PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX partitions;
DWORD partitionsSize = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) 
                       + 127 * sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
partitions = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(partitionsSize);

HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", FILE_ANY_ACCESS , 
                      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                      OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   // handle error and exit
}
if (DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, NULL, 0, partitions, 
                    partitionsSize, 0, NULL) != 0)
{
   // do stuff with partitions here
}
```

Данный код корректно отрабатывает на Windows 10, однако мне необходима совместимость с Windows 7. Приложение падает на вызове DeviceIoControl со следующим выводом отладчика: *Unhandled exception at 0x76B5D2EA (KernelBase.dll) in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.*

Для сборки использовал компилятор Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

Для решения испробовал следующее: менял параметры доступа в вызове CreateFile, запускал от имени администратора

Comment: ваша ошибка похожа на ошибку по памяти. DeviceIoControl может использоваться вплоть до хр. У вас проблемные места `partitions = ... malloc ...`. Необходимо добавить проверку, что память точно выделилась и `if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` необходимо корректно завершить программу, если устройство не может быть открыто.

Comment: Дополнтельно, попробуйте собрать приложение с флагами /MT для исключения зависимостей от студийного рантайма

Comment: @goldstar_labs флаг `/MT` не исключает зависимость от студийного рантайма, он задает статическую линковку этого рантайма.

Comment: Предпоследний параметр DeviceIoControl не может быть 0. В качестве него нужно передать указатель на DWORD.

Comment: @VTT Ну факт динамической линковки с чем-то обычно и называют "Зависимостью". Не понятно, однако, при чем это здесь. Из стандартной библиотеки у автора только malloc, который редко падает с ошибкой.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, действительно, невнимательно прочитал документацию. Один из двух параметров обязательно ненулевые. Только указатель на DWORD это предпоследний параметр. Это решило проблему. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове `DeviceIoControl` c флагом `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` без использования асинхронного чтения параметр `lpBytesReturned` должен быть ненулевым указателем, [согласно документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If `lpOverlapped` is `NULL`, `lpBytesReturned` cannot be `NULL`. Even when an operation returns no output data and lpOutBuffer is NULL, `DeviceIoControl` makes use of `lpBytesReturned`. After such an operation, the value of `lpBytesReturned` is meaningless.